# Keeping my footer at the bottom with responsive design using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How do i keep my footer at the bottom of the page even when I click the toggle for the sidebar? The footer I made is at the bottom but whenever i click the sidebar toggle it goes up like this

[image]

Im using bootstrap btw.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it. I'm not entirely happy with the outcome as the height of the footer is a fixed number (I would prefer if the height could be dynamic).

```
<div id="wrapper">
    All your contents, div, nav etc go in here
    <div id="push"></div> <!--add the push div here -->
</div>
<footer>
</footer>
```

The CSS:

```
#push, footer {
height:100px; /*or whatever height you need */
}
```

I'm not sure what your codes look like, so I can only hope that this helps.

Comment: I tried executing this but i still have the same problem whenever i click my sidebar toggle the footer i made at the bottom floats up. Btw thanks a lot here

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/examples/sticky-footer.html

It is a plugin which makes your footer sticky. You can find the code in the examples folder of your bootstrap download.

Comment: I already checked out what a sticky footer is, and i think its not the type of footer i was trying to do. I just need to have my footer at the bottom and avoid it from floating upwards whenever I click my sidebar toggle